# How do I parse the json in scala

Tags: json, scala, spark-streaming

I had spark streaming job which parsed kafka streaming record json by json4s, but there is a situation that I don't know how to deal with. every handled map of every json like this:

```
Map(new_userid -> 70048837, target_type -> category, deviceid -> 70f817d51b321217_afa3673c0804, click_url -> , platform -> android_app, page_section -> List(category_switch_bar), click_location -> )
```

take a look at the page_section, it is not what I need, I wanna the result is: `page_section -> "category_switch_bar"`, but the page_section is a list which has only a element or None. I code this:

```
val pageSection=  record.getOrElse("page_section", "")
```

but It is clear this is not right. How do I collect it?

Comment: what does the original JSON look like?

Comment: page_section is a json array which has only one element，such as:page_section:[“xxy”]，but sometimes it may be not exists in json map.i need to consider both situation

Comment: original json like this: {u'brand': u'samsung', u'page_section': [u'ABC'] ....}

Comment: maybe `record.getOrElse("page_section", List("")).head` or `record.get("page_section").map(_.head).getOrElse("")`

Comment: I had tried as you said, but it cannot be compiled well, the error is "can not resolve symbol head"

Comment: yeah, you are right, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

According to your json sample `page_section` is indeed a JSON list, so it's reasonably deserialized as Scala List.
If you're sure it's always either one or zero elements list and you're willing to convert it to a case class instead of Map, you can use custom `FieldSerializer` which will transform `JArray` to either `JString` or `JNull` and in case class that's going to be an `Option[String]` field

See json4s docs for more details https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-fields-of-a-class